# Trying to cycle through colors in Raphael with animation

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am trying to cycle through the spectrum of colors and animate it. But for some reason, it goes from black to red and then restarts that. I feel like I need to update the current color, but I am not sure quite how...

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1bpcj0g5/4/

**HTML**

```
<div id="clock"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var paper = Raphael('clock', 800, 800);

var clock = paper.circle(200, 200, 100);
var hand = paper.rect(200, 200, 5, 100);

var deg = 6;
var color = "#f00";

hand.attr("fill", "#000");

function changeColor()
{
    color = Raphael.getColor(1);
    var anim = Raphael.animation({ fill: color }, 6000).repeat(Infinity);
    clock.animate(anim);
}

function rotateHand() {
    deg = deg == 366 ? 6 : deg;
    hand.transform("r" + deg + ",200,200");
    deg += 6;
    clock.attr("fill", color);
}

changeColor();

window.setInterval(rotateHand, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Raphael.getColor is not working as per the [docs](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.getColor).

So, I have used this logic from [Paul Irish blog](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/) and modified your code little bit, to adopt the changes.

```
function changeColor()
{
    //code taken from the blog
    clock.animate({'fill': ('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16))}, 3000,"linear");
}

function rotateHand() {
    deg = deg == 366 ? 6 : deg;
    hand.transform("r" + deg + ",200,200");
    deg += 6;
}

changeColor();
window.setInterval(changeColor, 3000);
window.setInterval(rotateHand, 1000);
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1bpcj0g5/6/).